# Object desctructuring and assignment

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object, `json`, and I want to assign *some* of its properties to another object, `stn`.

```js
stn.closingTime = json.closingTime
stn.contactEmail = json.contactEmail
stn.contactPhone = json.contactPhone
stn.openingTime = json.openingTime
stn.priceFrom = json.priceFrom
stn.priceTo = json.priceTo
```

I know if I wanted to just have those properties in the global object context I could do

```js
{closingTime, contactEmail, contactPhone, etc....} = json
```

But how do I destructure those properties to another named object? (`stn` in this case)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const json = { closingTime: 'closingTime', contactEmail: 'contactEmail', contactPhone: 'contactPhone', openingTime: 'openingTime', priceFrom: 'priceFrom', priceTo: 'priceTo' };
const {
  contactPhone,
  openingTime,
  priceFrom,
  ...rest } = json;

const stn = {
  contactPhone,
  openingTime,
  priceFrom,
};
console.log(stn);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function and use Destructuring of parameters of function. Below is example code which gets `a` and `b` prop from obj.

```js
const obj = {a:'a',b:'b',c:'c'};
const stn = (({a,b}) => ({a,b}))(obj)
console.log(stn)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array of `keys` you need in `stn`. Then use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) like this:

```
Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, json[k]]))
```

Demo:

```js
const input = {
  closingTime: 'closing',
  contactEmail: 'Email',
  contactPhone: 'Phone',
  openingTime: 'Time',
  priceFrom: 'From',
  priceTo: 'To'
};

const getPartial = (obj, keys) => Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, obj[k]]))

console.log(getPartial(input, ['closingTime', 'contactEmail' ]))
console.log(getPartial(input, ['contactPhone', 'priceFrom', 'priceTo' ]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to copy *all* of the properties from `json`, then you can use `stn = {...json};`.

But since you'd only like to copy *some* of the properties from `json`, then what you're doing is pretty much the goto.

Comment: He want to other properties in an object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aliases` like this

```
// Grabs obj.x as as { otherName }
const { x: otherName } = obj;
```

Ref: https://davidwalsh.name/destructuring-alias

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `pickBy` function that create a new object from an object a list of keys. Reduce the keys array to a new object by checking if the exists in the original object, and add it, and it's respective value to the accumulated object.

```js
const input = {
  closingTime: 'closing',
  contactEmail: 'Email',
  contactPhone: 'Phone',
  openingTime: 'Time',
  priceFrom: 'From',
  priceTo: 'To'
}

const pickBy = (obj, keys) => keys.reduce((r, k) => k in obj ? { 
  ...r, [k]: obj[k] 
} : obj, {})

console.log(pickBy(input, ['closingTime', 'contactEmail']))
console.log(pickBy(input, ['contactPhone', 'priceFrom', 'priceTo']))
```

If you've need many properties from the original object, you can use destructuring and rest params to get a new object without the properties you don't want.

```js
const input = {
  closingTime: 'closing',
  contactEmail: 'Email',
  contactPhone: 'Phone',
  openingTime: 'Time',
  priceFrom: 'From',
  priceTo: 'To'
}

const { closingTime, contactEmail, ...result } = input

console.log(result)
```